# How to read a file of names into an array

Tags: c, string, scanf

I need help reading in a list of names and storing them into a string. I already allocated the memory for the strings, I just need help actually reading them and storing them in. Here is the information and code that I already written. I just need help with the `insert_data` function.

```
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define MAX_STRING_LEN 25 

void insert_data(char **strings, const char *filename, int size); 
void allocate(char ***strings, int size); 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){ 

   if(argc != 4){ 
      printf("Wrong number of args"); 
   } 

   char **pointer; 
   int size = atoi(argv[1]); 
   allocate(&pointer, size); 
   insert_data(pointer, argv[2], size);
} 



void allocate(char ***strings, int size){ 

   int i; 
   *strings = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char**) * size); 

    for( i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    { 
        (*strings)[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_STRING_LEN); 
    } 
}
```

This is the function that I need help with:

```
void insert_data(char **strings, const char *filename, int size){

    FILE *input;
    input = fopen(filename, "r");

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){

    fscanf(input,"%s", (*strings)[i]);

    }

    fclose(input);
}
```

Here is the list that I am reading in:

```
matt 
susan 
mark 
david 
aden 
phil 
erik 
john 
caden 
mycah
```

Comment: Open the file using `fopen`. Read the strings using `fscanf` to a temp string, then copy the string to `strings` array. After you finisf reading, close the file using `fclose`

Comment: You didn't even try anything? I've helped you in the last question because you seemed to have tried at least... but now you paste my code here (which is much harder to understand than a simple file reading) and expect someone to do your work? Do as @Don'tYouWorryChild said.. go find the documentation on those 3 functions.

Comment: Do some home work first. Ref http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/fscanf.html and try yourself how much you can then post the difficulty faced

Comment: sorry guys, i updated the code with what i tried, I keep getting a seg fault though.

Comment: search for the %s option... %c reads a character and you will need to send an address if you want to read a single char

Comment: What's your compiler? If you're using GCC, make sure you use `-Wall` to catch `printf`-style format string/argument errors.

Comment: Yes, I knew that, that was a dumb mistake by my part. I am still getting a segmentation fault though.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define MAX_STRING_LEN 25 
#define _S(x) #x
#define S(x) _S(x)

void insert_data(char **strings, const char *filename, int size); 
void allocate(char ***strings, int size); 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){ 

    if(argc != 3){ 
        printf("Wrong number of args\n");
        printf("Usage:%s size filename\n", argv[0] ? argv[0] : "prog");
        exit(-1);
    } 

    char **pointer; 
    int size = atoi(argv[1]); 
    allocate(&pointer, size); 
    insert_data(pointer, argv[2], size);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;++i){
        printf("%s\n", pointer[i]);
        free(pointer[i]);
    }
    free(pointer);
    return 0;
}

void allocate(char ***strings, int size){ 
    int i; 

    *strings = malloc(sizeof(char*) * size); 
    for( i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        (*strings)[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (MAX_STRING_LEN+1)); 
    }
} 

void insert_data(char **strings, const char *filename, int size){
    FILE *input= fopen(filename, "r");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        fscanf(input,"%" S(MAX_STRING_LEN)  "s", strings[i]);
    }
    fclose(input);
}
```